# How to enable background sync in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, service-worker

I have a web app that i used electron to make it usable as a desktop app.
It uses service worker to make the app work offline. Any actions done on the tab change the local indexeddb and then add a task to the outbox. The service worker is triggered using registration.sync.register and it then clears the outbox.
This works fine on chrome but on electron i get an error:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Background Sync is disabled.`

Any idea how to get around this ?